# SharePoint 2013 Powershell - Moving Document Liobrary to New Site Collection

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to move document libraries, from one site collection to another and retain of the metadata such as Modified By, Date Modified etc.

I have tried using the 'move' function within SharePoint 2013 Content and Structure but unfortunately this doesn't extend to across site collections.

I have tried multiple PowerShell scripts they successfully copy the file from one Site Collection to another but do not retain the metadata.

Any ideas, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried saving the library as a template? You can mark the template to keep the contents.

Then you can deploy a new library from that template (Site actions / More options / *Template name*), and after that delete the template.

Additionally you can move it between servers. Go to the Site settings, there to the template gallery and download the template you just created. Now you can move it to another server or application.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SharePoint migration tools. Some of them offer free trials for limited amounts of data.